# Animate UICollectionView Cell Insert along a curved path

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a circular UICollectionView that places each item an even distance apart from each other along a circular path. When you insert an item I'm specifying it's starting position in

`- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath`

Then, from how I understand, the layout will perform an animation from the start point, to the point you specify in `- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path`

This results in a straight line animation, from point A to point B. What I would like is to be able to specify the path for the animation, so that it will move along a curved path rather than a straight one.

Any ideas?